# How to scrape specific text from a webpage in Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to quickly obtain the day's exchange rate from www.xoom.com

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.xoom.com')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

Next, after viewing the source code of this webpage I know that exchange rate is mentioned here:

```
<p class="xcma-fx-rate">Current locked-in exchange rate* <em class="fx-rate">1 USD = 60.1500 INR</em></p>
```

I tried several things like:

```
soup.find_all('div class')
```

But it gives me an empty array:  []

How do I scrape the exchange rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
text_rate = soup.find('em',attrs={'class':'fx-rate'}).getText()
```

Also, using `lmxl` , assuming that the element is reaaly on the page, you can get rate by this code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

r = requests.get('https://www.xoom.com/india/send-money')
data = r.text

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

rate = tree.xpath("//em[@class='fx-rate']")

print rate[0].text_content()
```

prints `1 USD = 60.1500 INR`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: So, are you sure that this: `<p class="xcma-fx-rate">Current locked-in exchange rate* <em class="fx-rate">1 USD = 60.1500 INR</em></p>` is really in source? I opened your page and didn't find there element `em` with `class` fx-rate

Comment: can you attach screenshot of where is this rate on that page?

Comment: Ahhh!! Right. Thank you for drawing my attention to that. Actually, because I have opened that website a lot of times, when I open it in browser it automatically shows me an 'india' exchange rate page at homepage address (after checking some cookie stored in my machine I guess). But this doesn't happen when I'm fetching with Python. This is where the rate is mentioned: https://www.xoom.com/india/send-money

Comment: try that code in my answer now with new URL :) I mean `text_rate = soup.find('em',attrs={'class':'fx-rate'}).getText()` Well, seems you got it eventually :) you'r welcome!

Comment: I've also updated `lxml` version of how to extract text from there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I was fetching the wrong page.

Because I have opened that website a lot of times, when I open it in my browser it automatically shows me an 'india' exchange rate page at the homepage address (after checking some cookie stored in my machine I guess). But this doesn't happen when I'm fetching with Python. So I need to explicitly state the right page to fetch. This is where the rate is mentioned: xoom.com/india/send-money

Now the correct code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.xoom.com/india/send-money')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for rate in soup.find_all('em'):
    print rate.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the code provided as I am scraping as well and I think I found the solution for this one:

You can replace the link if you want:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

r = requests.get('https://www.xoom.com/philippines/send-money')
data = r.text
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
rate = tree.xpath("//div[@class='js-exchange-rate']")

rate[0].text_content()
```

I am using Python 3.8 and Anaconda

The result was:

```
' 1 USD = 49.1238 PHP* '
```